# xpath one line doesn't get me the link

Tags: xpath, scrapy

What I want is that the spider engine recognizes the link to next page.

[image]

This is this page `http://quotes.toscrape.com/`

I have two variants. The first one which is css syntax based, works, but the second one (which I want the xpath version to be, doesn't)

```
next_page_url = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

//this below does not work

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('/a[contains(@href,"next")]/@href').extract_first()
```

So while I can go along with css, I am still curious at knowing what is incorrect with the given xpath syntax that makes it not give the results of its css equivalent.

thank you

it goes here:

```
#follow pagination link
next_page_url = response.css('li.next > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
if next_page_url:
   next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
   yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url,callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering provided HTML target link doesn't contain `"next"` in `@href`. Try below expression:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('/a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract_first()
```

If you want exact analogue of your CSS selector:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('/li[contains(@class, "next")]/a/@href').extract_first()
```

Comment: I tried both of your versions and it just stays on page one. I am trying to go past this page. http://quotes.toscrape.com/

Comment: Dod you try `requests.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/" + next_page_url)`?

Comment: I have been one day with this, so I m still learning, dont know where to add that. I have added the block of code where the line in question goes.

Comment: Actually I don't use Scrapy, so I can't advice you something more than correct XPath... Try to printout `next_page_url`. Does it return you `"http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/"`?